# How to read an IO object into another

Tags: ruby

If I have one IO object that will be written to, and one IO object that is read from, how can I easily pipe one into another?

My use case is roughly:

```
require "open3"
# File < IO
files = [File.open('1.sql'), File.open('2.sql')]
input, waiters = Open3.pipeline_w("mysql") # input is an IO
files.each do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
        input.write line
    end
end
input.close
Process.wait waiters[0].pid
```

One alternative is to use `Open3.pipeline('cat myfile.sql', 'mysql')`, but then I wouldn't be able to start `mysql` only once for all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IO.copy_stream](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-copy_stream):

```
files = [File.open('1.sql'), File.open('2.sql')]
mysql = IO.popen('mysql','w') # Spawn a `mysql` process for writing to its `STDIN`, returns an `IO`
files.each do |file|
  IO.copy_stream(file, mysql) # Takes two `IO` objects, reads from first and writes to second
  file.close()
end
mysql.close()
```

Feel free to omit the `close()` calls if your method/program is over now, as file handles will be automatically closed.
Note it might be dangerous to open an unlimited number of files at once (there's a limit of open files per process), so consider opening and closing them one by one.